# Google Sheets same formula and same input text produce different results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When I use the same formula `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(SPLIT(A2,"€"),1),","."))` and the same input text `17,70 €` in different sheets within the same Google sheet, I get different results. Why?

[image: Error]

and

[image]

Comment: Please share a sample sheet for your failing case.[Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know for sure without seeing the sheets, but it's probably down to one of the values being formatted as a number and the other as text.

Alternatively, it might be a difference in the 'locale' setting if you have two different sheets.

[image]

[image]